# Substitute Obfuscated PHP strings in Sed

Tags: php, string, bash, sed, substitution

I'm writing a script to deobfuscate PHP code. And mostly it's done;the only thing left is to decode the strings within the code. So my input file could be something like:

```
    <?php
     $myString="\x48\x45\x4c\x4c\x4f"; 
     $myOtherString="\x57\x4F\x52\x4C\x44";
    ?>
```

Now, in my Script I have a loop over all the strings to replace them one by one. Therefore I have (as part of the loop) the following code ($S is declared as the obfuscated String inside the loop - just in case you were wondering where $S comes from):

```
    $S='"\x48\x45\x4c\x4c\x4f"'
    REALSTRING=`php -r 'eval("echo ".$argv[1].";");' $S`
    ESCAPEDREALSTRING=`printf "%q" "$REALSTRING"`
    ESCAPEDSOURCE=`printf "%q" "$S"`
    CODE4=`echo $CODE4 | sed "s/$ESCAPEDSOURCE/$ESCAPEDREALSTRING/g"`
```

I have searched the web for a solution and the printf step was recommended to escape the string correctly. Some of the strings in the real text are even RegExes, so maybe Sed is not suitable for the job. Does anybody have an idea?

This attempt is using sed, but perl, awk or any other tool is also fine, as long as available in Bash per default on a standard Linux/MacOS system.

As an example pair:
`"\x5c\50\x22\133\x30\55\x39\101\x2d\132\x61\55\x7a\134\x2b\5‌​7\x3d\135\x2a\42\x5c‌​\51"`
should be converted to
`"\("[0-9A-Za-z\+/=]*"\)"`
This is one of the possibly occurring RegEx I mentioned.

Best regards
Merlin

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output. Please provide more code context, if you have to explain what `$S` your mcve seems to be be lacking on the "C".

Comment: Sure. As an example pair: `"\x5c\50\x22\133\x30\55\x39\101\x2d\132\x61\55\x7a\134\x2b\57\x3d\135\x2a\42\x5c\51"` should be converted to `\("[0-9A-Za-z\+/=]*"\)`. And this is one of the RegEx I mentioned.

Comment: I edited it for better understanding. In fact, `"` *is* part of the input.

Comment: If the `"` are part of the input (sorry for misguessing), then don't you want them also kept in the result? Please delete my wrong guess from your question. I could, but would probably just get in your way while you edit.

Comment: You are completely right. It's actually my mistake. To explain: `"\x5c\50\x22\133\x30\55\x39\101\x2d\132\x61\55\x7a\134\x2b\5‌​7\x3d\135\x2a\42\x5c‌​\51"` has to become `"\("[0-9A-Za-z\+/=]*"\)"`. This includes in both cases the double quote.

Comment: To explain: I see `\x5c` twice and assume that they are "\". I assume that a string in input php is represented within `"` and should also be in output; even if it is a regex. I am not fluent in php I should mention.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I edited it into question (might not be visible for you yet). You can edit yourself, that is probably sooner visible.

Comment: The input is a quoted string (that's how I need it to be evaluated by PHP). And on the other hand I want to substitute _the quoted_ text by _a quoted version_ of the plain text. But if it's easier to handle by sed, I could remove the quotes from the source es well...

Comment: The problem itself seems to be beyond what is easily done with sed. Would you also accept solutions in perl or awk? In that case you might want to tag those languages, too.

Comment: Yes sure. Anything (as long as available in Bash per default on a standard Linux/MacOS system) will be ok.

Comment: Tagging more than 5 is not allowed, I was not aware of that, so no need to try. I added the perl/awk info as text to the question.

Comment: I guess I'm going to stick to Python, which is not the most elegant way, but serves my purpose: `python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv[1].replace(sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3])'` should do the trick...but if anybody has a better solution, I'm open to suggestions!